# Sequentially Load DIV using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to load a series of DIVS using Jquery using a preloader.

For instance, I have a page with 4 divs nested within 1 main div.

I'd like to load content1, then content2, and so on.

Plus, only 1 div will load at a time in the sequence.

Is this possible with jquery, or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use [jQuery.load();](http://api.jquery.com/load/), begin with Content1 and trigger the loading of Content2 on the *complete* callback from .load();.

**Example:**

```
$("#Div1").load("ajax/Content1.php", function() {
  $("#Div2").load("ajax/Content2.php", function() {
    //(And so on...)
  });
});
```

**Edit:** I just assumed by "load" you meant loading dynamic (like PHP which your post is tagged with) content through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just when you set up the load command for each, put a delay command to time them so they happen in sequence. So, if you have for divs with the ids div-1, div-2, div-3, and div-4:

```
jQuery("#div-1").fadeIn(3000)
jQuery("#div-2").delay(3000).fadeIn(3000)
jQuery("#div-3").delay(6000).fadeIn(3000)
jQuery("#div-4").delay(9000).fadeIn(3000)
```