# Huge data entry webform performance

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, performance

I have a webform that allows users to dynamically add 'sections' (which are divs with about 20 data items) to the existing form.  The issue as expected is the load times.  I have looked at [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293779/sequentially-load-div-using-jquery) Now I am wondering if there is a way to start the loading x number of sections after the view port. I don't have the control to change the app.  I have been tasked with making it hurt less.  I am open to ideas.

My thanks in advance,

Comment: Additional clarification: I Programmatically creat and populate an instance of an ascx for each 'section' that exists. I was looking at the jQuery .Delay() on the other page. The content is data driven and not in separate physical file locations. Sorry I was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method you referred to in the other post...

```
var x = 10;

for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    $('#div' + i).load('content' + i + '.php');
}
```

Comment: I think this would work if the content sections were separate files. I have clarified my post with more details.